# Intuition Behind Function of a Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm trying to understand the intuition behind the formula for a random variable which is a function of another random variable. Formula: ${\sum}f(x_i)/g'(x_i)$

I tried to take as example a fair dice: 1,...,6 is coming out at $1/6$. But if we use the formula for $y=x^2$, than we won't get 1/6 for 36 as we expect. Why is that?

Could someone explain me the intuition behind this formula?

Comment: What exactly is $\sum f(x_i)/g'(x_i)$ supposed to compute? What is $f$? $g$? $x_i$?

Comment: Hi @kccu, sorry i saw you have tons of reputation so I thought you are laughing at me. So first of all, I'm writing frkm my cell phone, so I don't have preview and I cannot always add functions as you do. It took me 5-8 minutes to write this one.. Regarding the function, this is a common function from the 1st part of average course with statistics that no student from as far as I know can understand. So I was hoping that someone who's pro enough in this field will recognize tge topic & the problem and will reply me. Thanks though, but I think it's clear enough.

Comment: And as for the other parts, I also struggle to understand them now. :)

Comment: You can still describe in words what these things are supposed to mean. I'm not trying to be harsh, but I really honestly can't answer your question because I don't know what you are trying to ask.

Comment: There is a new random variable Y=g(x), given $f_x(X)$, we are trying to find using the formula $f_y(Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a classic example that explains where the formula you mentioned comes from:

Suppose $Y = X^n$ then, by the definition of a CDF:
$$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X^n \leq y) = P(X \leq y^{(1/n)})$$
Therefore,
$$F_Y(y) = F_X(y^{(1/n)})$$ and we differentiate (using the chain rule)
$$f_Y(y) = \frac {1}{n} y^{\frac {1}{n} -1}*f_X(y^{\frac{1}{n}})$$
Written concisely, this is the formula:
$$f_Y(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{i} \frac {f(x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|}$$ 
Where you solve $Y = g(x)$ for $x_i$

Comment: Clark could you help me to understand it a little bit more? It's not clear to me, for instance (0,1) ~ U э x => f(x)=1. What is f($x^2$)? Where is it defined? According to the function it is a function that is going down and not unified. Or does it not having an answer here since X~U and has infinite number of roots to some square?

Comment: No need. I'll explain (you answered tge question). This sum is defined for *continous* X. For dice we can put 0s in between the results. Beautiful, huh? The function has non intuition, the only way it comes out is of CDF, the F function that you showed. Many thanks!